# How to make a query based on multiple checkbox value

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I want to make a query based on the input of the checkboxes.

This is wat i made:

```
       <form action="#" method="GET" id="filter"> 
<input type="checkbox" name="toe[]" value="ja">ja<br /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="toe[]" value="misschien">misschien<br/> 
<input type="checkbox" name="toe[]" value="nee">nee<br/>
 <input type="submit" name="kies" value="Kies" /> 
</form>


 if(isset($_GET['toe']) && count($_GET['toe'] > 0)) { 
$toeid = implode(',', $_GET['toe']);
$toeid = mysql_real_escape_string($toeid); 
}

$sql = "SELECT  * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE TOEGEZEGD = '$toeid'
ORDER BY $field $sort";
```

This works, but only if 1 checkbox is checked, otherwise i get an output of ja,nee and that doesn't work.

I also want (if possible) that on return the checkbox ticked in the query will kept ticked. But the first is the important, the rest will come.

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Thank you for the warning, but this is not a option at this moment for me

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `WHERE TOEGEZEGD IN (...)` clause instead of what you have here. This requires escaping all of the incoming parameters individually and joining them with a comma.

Comment: Can i make the query like this you mean ?  WHERE TOEGEZEGD IN ('$toeid') ?

Comment: It will look like `IN('ja','nee')` when it's properly escaped.

Comment: Oke, i made the query like this:                                 $sql = "SELECT  * 
FROM `sponsoren` 
WHERE TOEGEZEGD IN ('$catid')  which does not give error but also not the right outcome, when echo $catid it says ja,nee and not 'ja','nee'. How do i change that ?
ORDER BY $field $sort";

Comment: What you need to do is use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to convert the arguments: `$cat_ids = implode(",", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET['toe']))` It's worth noting this is is a complete non-issue in a modern 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that has a full database layer.

Comment: I do understand that my way (mysql,php) is old and out of date but for this moment i just have to get i working so that we (very small organization of 6 people) can use it until the summer. I'm not able to stop it and learn myself a new way and get i working in a few weeks. When it works i will have time to set up a new 'version' using more mordern ways.  thanks for the help

Comment: Good to hear. It's just a lot easier to develop little apps like this using a framework than to have to hack around with stuff like writing raw SQL queries, *especially* for a small group of people.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['toe']) && count($_GET['toe'] > 0)) { 
$toeid = implode(",", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_GET['telefoon']));
}   Using this does not solve it, it still only works when using one checkbox

Comment: What sort of query does that generate? You should be seeing stuff like `IN ('a','b')` for checkboxes "a" and "b". Are you sure `$_GET['toe']` is an array? Also why are you using the `telefoon` identifier in there?

Comment: (telefoon = toe , misstype).  i echo $toeid, it comes back with whatever i check. ja or nee or misschien. In that case the query returns rows where TOEGEZEGD is one of these. But when i checked 2 boxes it echo's ja,nee (or whatever i checked and the query comes empty (no rows). Then i tried instead of WHERE TOEGEZEGD IN ('$toeid') , WHERE TOEGEZEGD IN('ja','nee') and then it works. So i get the impression that $toeid put in: ja,nee instead of: 'ja','nee'

Comment: You may need to write a wrapper function that puts the quotes on the beginning and end of each string. It's massive irritations like this that make `mysql_query` such a waste of time.